# How to create Shapeless HMap from from var arg list

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm creating shapeless HMap using the code like below from [scala-exercises.](https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/HMap)

```
import shapeless.HMap

class BiMapIS[K, V]
implicit val intToString = new BiMapIS[Int, String]
implicit val stringToInt = new BiMapIS[String, Int]

val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](23 -> "foo", "bar" -> 13)
```

I would like to create HMap from variable arguments as below (I'm having long list of arguments so just checking whether I can simplify the code littlebit) -

```
import shapeless.{HMap, HNil}
import java.util.{List => JList}
val entities: JList[(_, _)] = ???
class BiMapIS[K, V]
implicit val intToString = new BiMapIS[Int, String]
implicit val stringToInt = new BiMapIS[String, Int]
import collection.JavaConverters._
val entitiesSeq = entities.asScala.toList
val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](entitiesSeq:_*)
```

Is there any way I can create HMap from variable args?

I'm using shapless 2.33 with scala 2.12 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.12/2.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
val entitiesSeq = entities.asScala.toMap[Any, Any]
val hm = new HMap[BiMapIS](entitiesSeq)
```

Comment: I get error at line `val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](entitiesSeq)` : type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Any]
[error]  required: (?, ?)
[error]   val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](entitiesSeq)
[error]                          ^
[error] one error found

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan In my answer there is `new` in this line.